# MFC: Create tooltip for a Tab in CTabView

Tags: c++, mfc, tooltip

I want to create a ToolTip for a tab on a `CTabView` which is in one of the `CSplitterWnd` panes.  In this case the tab is a `CHtmlView`. I put the `CToolTipCtrl m_ToolTip` in the `CMainFrame` as `public`. I create it on `OnCreate()`, then attempt to add test text to it on `OnInitialUpdate()` of the `CHtmlView` tab item.  But when hovering over the tab or client area of the tab, no tool tip shows. What am I doing wrong or missing?

```
int CMainFrame::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
  // ...
  m_ToolTip.Create(this);

  return 0;
}

BOOL CMainFrame::OnCreateClient(LPCREATESTRUCT lpcs, CCreateContext* pContext)
{
  // create spliter windows - one of which will end up with CTabView 
}

// One of the tabs in the CTabView is based on CHtmlView
void CMyHtmlView::OnInitialUpdate()
{
  __super::OnInitialUpdate();

  CToolTipCtrl &tooltip=((CMainFrame*) AfxGetMainWnd())->m_ToolTip;
  tooltip.AddTool(this, _T("Test Tooltip"));
  tooltip.Activate(TRUE);
}
```

Abandoning the above, I implemented the suggestion on page 941-942 in the book *Programming Windows with MFC second Edition* to derive from `CToolTipCtrl` and implement new functions that use `TTF_SUBCLASS`. I tried it with in the `CMyTabView` on the client area of the tabs. It sort of works with the Edit and Rich Views but not HTML view. By sort of, I mean, it works maybe twice then doesn't come up again. Here's that part:

```
int CMyTabView::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
  if (CTabView::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
    return -1;

  AddView(RUNTIME_CLASS(CMyEditView), _T("Tab1"));
  AddView(RUNTIME_CLASS(CMyRichView), _T("Tab2"));
  AddView(RUNTIME_CLASS(CMyHtmlView), _T("Tab3"));

  m_ToolTip.Create(this, TTS_ALWAYSTIP);

  CMFCTabCtrl &tabctrl=GetTabControl();
  for (int i=0; i < tabctrl.GetTabsNum(); ++i) {
    m_ToolTip.AddWindowTool(tabctrl.GetTabWnd(i), _T("Test Tool Tip"));
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Not working on the HTML View was fine because I really just want it on the tab.   So I change it up and got rid of the stuff above (except the `.Create`) and added:

```
void CMyTabView::OnInitialUpdate()
{
  CTabView::OnInitialUpdate();

  CMFCTabCtrl &tabctrl=GetTabControl();
  CRect rc;
  tabctrl.GetTabsRect(rc);
  if (!rc.IsRectEmpty()) {
    m_ToolTip.AddRectTool(&tabctrl, _T("test tip"), &rc, (UINT_PTR) tabctrl.GetSafeHwnd());
  }
}
```

But that doesn't work. It tried using `this` as well, still didn't work. So while something worked, still can't get it to work on the tabs? Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think `CMFCTabCtrl` and `CTabView` are related. You should show screen shot.

Comment: GetTabControl() is part of CTabView.